# file mapping vs file system synchronization

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I have a file with some data, which is also memory-mapped. So that I have both file descriptor and the pointer to the mapped pages. Mostly the data is only read from the mapping, but eventually it's also modified.

The modification consists of modifying some data within the file (sort of headers update), plus appending some new data (i.e. writing post the current end of the file).

This data structure is accessed from different threads, and to prevent collisions I synchronize access to it (mutex and friends).

During the modification I use both the file mapping and the file descriptor. Headers are updated implicitly by modifying the mapped memory, whereas the new data is written to the file by the appropriate API (`WriteFile` on windows, `write` on posix). Worth to note that the new data and the headers belong to different pages.

Since the modification changes the file size, the memory mapping is re-initialized after every such a modification. That is, it's unmapped, and then mapped again (with the new size).

I realize that writes to the mapped memory are "asynchronous" wrt file system, and order is not guaranteed, but I thought there was no problem because I explicitly close the file mapping, which should (IMHO) act as a sort of a flushing point.

Now this works without problem on windows, but on linux (android to be exact) eventually the mapped data turns-out to be inconsistent temporarily (i.e. data is ok when retrying). Seems like it doesn't reflect the newly-appended data.

Do I have to call some synchronization API to ensure the data if flushed properly? If so, which one should I use: `sync`, `msync`, `syncfs` or something different?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

This is a pseudo-code that illustrates the scenario I'm dealing with.
(The real code is more complex of course)

```
struct CompressedGrid
{
    mutex m_Lock;
    int m_FileHandle;    
    void* m_pMappedMemory;

    Hdr* get_Hdr() { return /* the mapped memory with some offset*/; }

    void SaveGridCell(int idx, const Cell& cCompressed)
    {
        AutoLock scope(m_Lock);

        // Write to mapped memory
        get_Hdr()->m_pCellOffset[Idx] = /* current end of file */;

        // Append the data
        lseek64(m_FileHandle, 0, FILE_END);
        write(m_FileHandle, cCompressed.pPtr, cCompressed.nSize);

        // re-map
        munmap(...);
        m_pMappedMemory = mmap(...); // specify the new file size of course
    }

    bool DecodeGridCell(int idx, Cell& cRaw)
    {
        AutoLock scope(m_Lock);

        uint64_t nOffs = get_Hdr()->m_pCellOffset[Idx] = /* ;
        if (!nOffs)
            return false; // unavail

        const uint8_t* p = m_pMappedMemory + nOffs;

        cRaw.DecodeFrom(p); // This is where the problem appears!

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: There are `fsync(fd)` and `msync()`. I guess you should call them after each change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`addr = mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE, fd, offset)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to map the file.

If the size of the file changes, use [`newaddr = mremap(addr, len, newlen, MREMAP_MAYMOVE)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) to update the mapping to reflect it.  To extend the file, use [`ftruncate(fd, newlen)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) before remapping the file.

You can use [`mprotect(addr, len, protflags)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) to change the protection (read/write) on any pages in the mapping (both must be aligned on a page boundary). You can also tell the kernel about your future accesses via [`madvise()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), if the mapping is too large to fit in memory at once, but the kernel seems pretty darned good at managing readahead etc. even without those.

When you make changes to the mapping, use [`msync(partaddr, partlen, MS_SYNC | MS_INVALIDATE)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msync.2.html) or `msync(partaddr, partlen, MS_ASYNC | MS_INVALIDATE)` to ensure the changes int `partlen` chars from `partaddr` forward are visible to other mappings and file readers. If you use `MS_SYNC`, the call returns only when the update is complete. The `MS_ASYNC` call tells the kernel to do the update, but won't wait until it is done. If there are no other memory maps of the file, the `MS_INVALIDATE` does nothing; but if there are, that tells the kernel to ensure the changes are reflected in those too.

In Linux kernels since 2.6.19, `MS_ASYNC` does nothing, as the kernel tracks the changes properly anyway (no `msync()` is needed, except possibly before `munmap()`). I don't know if Android kernels have patches that change that behaviour; I suspect not. It is still a good idea to keep them in the code, for portability across POSIXy systems.

> mapped data turns-out to be inconsistent temporarily

Well, unless you do use `msync(partaddr, partlen, MS_SYNC | MS_INVALIDATE)`, the kernel will do the update when it sees best.

So, if you need some changes to be visible to file readers before proceeding, use `msync(areaptr, arealen, MS_SYNC | MS_INVALIDATE)` in the process doing those updates.

If you don't care about the exact moment, use `msync(areaptr, arealen, MS_ASYNC | MS_INVALIDATE)`. It'll be a no-op on current Linux kernels, but it's a good idea to keep them for portability (perhaps commented out, if necessary for performance) and to remind developers about the (lack of) synchronization expectations.

---

As I commented to OP, I cannot observe the synchronization issues on Linux at all. (That does not mean it does not happen on Android, because Android kernels are *derivatives* of Linux kernels, not exactly the same.)

I do believe the `msync()` call is not needed on Linux kernels since 2.6.19 at all, as long as the mapping uses flags `MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE`, and the underlying file is not opened using the `O_DIRECT` flag.  The reason for this belief is that in this case, both mapping and file accesses should use the exact same page cache pages.

Here are two test programs, that can be used to explore this on Linux. First, a single-process test, **test-single.c**:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static inline int read_from(const int fd, void *const to, const size_t len, const off_t offset)
{
    char       *p = (char *)to;
    char *const q = (char *)to + len;
    ssize_t     n;

    if (lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_SET) != offset)
        return errno = EIO;

    while (p < q) {
        n = read(fd, p, (size_t)(q - p));
        if (n > 0)
            p += n;
        else
        if (n != -1)
            return errno = EIO;
        else
        if (errno != EINTR)
            return errno;
    }

    return 0;
}

static inline int write_to(const int fd, const void *const from, const size_t len, const off_t offset)
{
    const char *const q = (const char *)from + len;
    const char       *p = (const char *)from;
    ssize_t           n;

    if (lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_SET) != offset)
        return errno = EIO;

    while (p < q) {
        n = write(fd, p, (size_t)(q - p));
        if (n > 0)
            p += n;
        else
        if (n != -1)
            return errno = EIO;
        else
        if (errno != EINTR)
            return errno;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long  tests, n, merrs = 0, werrs = 0;
    size_t         page;
    long          *map, data[2];
    int            fd;
    char           dummy;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s FILENAME COUNT\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program will test synchronization between a memory map\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "and reading/writing the underlying file, COUNT times.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[2], " %lu %c", &tests, &dummy) != 1 || tests < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid number of tests to run.\n", argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Create the file. */
    page = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot create file: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (ftruncate(fd, page) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot resize file: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        unlink(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Map it. */
    map = mmap(NULL, page, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_NORESERVE, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot map file: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        unlink(argv[1]);
        close(fd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Test loop. */
    for (n = 0; n < tests; n++) {

        /* Update map. */
        map[0] = (long)(n + 1);
        map[1] = (long)(~n);

        /* msync(map, 2 * sizeof map[0], MAP_SYNC | MAP_INVALIDATE); */

        /* Check the file contents. */
        if (read_from(fd, data, sizeof data, 0)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "read_from() failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            munmap(map, page);
            unlink(argv[1]);
            close(fd);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        werrs += (data[0] != (long)(n + 1) || data[1] != (long)(~n));

        /* Update data. */
        data[0] = (long)(n * 386131);
        data[1] = (long)(n * -257);
        if (write_to(fd, data, sizeof data, 0)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "write_to() failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            munmap(map, page);
            unlink(argv[1]);
            close(fd);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        merrs += (map[0] != (long)(n * 386131) || map[1] != (long)(n * -257));
    }

    munmap(map, page);
    unlink(argv[1]);
    close(fd);

    if (!werrs && !merrs)
        printf("No errors detected.\n");
    else {
        if (!werrs)
            printf("Detected %lu times (%.3f%%) when file contents were incorrect.\n",
                   werrs, 100.0 * (double)werrs / (double)tests);
        if (!merrs)
            printf("Detected %lu times (%.3f%%) when mapping was incorrect.\n",
                   merrs, 100.0 * (double)merrs / (double)tests);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile and run using e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -O2 test-single -o single
./single temp 1000000
```

to test a million times, whether the mapping and the file contents stay in sync, when both accesses are done in the same process.  Note that the `msync()` call is commented out, because on my machine it is not needed: I never see any errors/desynchronization during testing even without it.

The test rate on my machine is about 550,000 tests per second. Note that each tests does it both ways, so includes a read and a write. I just cannot get this to detect any errors. It is written to be quite sensitive to errors, too.

The second test program uses two child processes and a POSIX realtime signal to tell the other process to check the contents. **test-multi.c**:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define  NOTIFY_SIGNAL  (SIGRTMIN+0)

int mapper_process(const int fd, const size_t len)
{
    long       value = 1, count[2] = { 0, 0 };
    long      *data;
    siginfo_t  info;
    sigset_t   sigs;
    int        signum;

    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mapper_process(): Invalid file descriptor.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    data = mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE, fd, 0);
    if (data == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mapper_process(): Cannot map file.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    sigemptyset(&sigs);
    sigaddset(&sigs, NOTIFY_SIGNAL);
    sigaddset(&sigs, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&sigs, SIGHUP);
    sigaddset(&sigs, SIGTERM);

    while (1) {
        /* Wait for the notification. */
        signum = sigwaitinfo(&sigs, &info);
        if (signum == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            fprintf(stderr, "mapper_process(): sigwaitinfo() failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            munmap(data, len);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (signum != NOTIFY_SIGNAL)
            break;

        /* A notify signal was received. Check the write counter. */
        count[ (data[0] == value) ]++;

        /* Update. */
        data[0] = value++;
        data[1] = -(value++);

        /* Synchronize */
        /* msync(data, 2 * sizeof (data[0]), MS_SYNC | MS_INVALIDATE); */

        /* And let the writer know. */
        kill(info.si_pid, NOTIFY_SIGNAL);
    }

    /* Print statistics. */
    printf("mapper_process(): %lu errors out of %lu cycles (%.3f%%)\n",
           count[0], count[0] + count[1], 100.0 * (double)count[0] / (double)(count[0] + count[1]));
    fflush(stdout);

    munmap(data, len);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static inline int read_from(const int fd, void *const to, const size_t len, const off_t offset)
{
    char       *p = (char *)to;
    char *const q = (char *)to + len;
    ssize_t     n;

    if (lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_SET) != offset)
        return errno = EIO;

    while (p < q) {
        n = read(fd, p, (size_t)(q - p));
        if (n > 0)
            p += n;
        else
        if (n != -1)
            return errno = EIO;
        else
        if (errno != EINTR)
            return errno;
    }

    return 0;
}

static inline int write_to(const int fd, const void *const from, const size_t len, const off_t offset)
{
    const char *const q = (const char *)from + len;
    const char       *p = (const char *)from;
    ssize_t           n;

    if (lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_SET) != offset)
        return errno = EIO;

    while (p < q) {
        n = write(fd, p, (size_t)(q - p));
        if (n > 0)
            p += n;
        else
        if (n != -1)
            return errno = EIO;
        else
        if (errno != EINTR)
            return errno;
    }

    return 0;
}

int writer_process(const int fd, const size_t len, const pid_t other)
{
    long       data[2] = { 0, 0 }, count[2] = { 0, 0 };
    long       value = 0;
    siginfo_t  info;
    sigset_t   sigs;
    int        signum;

    sigemptyset(&sigs);
    sigaddset(&sigs, NOTIFY_SIGNAL);
    sigaddset(&sigs, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&sigs, SIGHUP);
    sigaddset(&sigs, SIGTERM);

    while (1) {

        /* Update. */
        data[0] = ++value;
        data[1] = -(value++);

        /* then write the data. */
        if (write_to(fd, data, sizeof data, 0)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "writer_process(): write_to() failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        /* Let the mapper know. */
        kill(other, NOTIFY_SIGNAL);

        /* Wait for the notification. */        
        signum = sigwaitinfo(&sigs, &info);
        if (signum == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            fprintf(stderr, "writer_process(): sigwaitinfo() failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (signum != NOTIFY_SIGNAL || info.si_pid != other)
            break;

        /* Reread the file. */
        if (read_from(fd, data, sizeof data, 0)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "writer_process(): read_from() failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        /* Check the read counter. */
        count[ (data[1] == -value) ]++;
    }

    /* Print statistics. */
    printf("writer_process(): %lu errors out of %lu cycles (%.3f%%)\n",
           count[0], count[0] + count[1], 100.0 * (double)count[0] / (double)(count[0] + count[1]));
    fflush(stdout);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timespec  duration;
    double           seconds;
    pid_t            mapper, writer, p;
    size_t           page;
    siginfo_t        info;
    sigset_t         sigs;
    int              fd, status;
    char             dummy;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s FILENAME SECONDS\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program will test synchronization between a memory map\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "and reading/writing the underlying file.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "The test will run for the specified time, or indefinitely\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "if SECONDS is zero, but you can also interrupt it with\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Ctrl+C (INT signal).\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[2], " %lf %c", &seconds, &dummy) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid number of seconds to run.\n", argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (seconds > 0) {
        duration.tv_sec = (time_t)seconds;
        duration.tv_nsec = (long)(1000000000 * (seconds - (double)(duration.tv_sec)));
    } else {
        duration.tv_sec = 0;
        duration.tv_nsec = 0;
    }

    /* Block INT, HUP, CHLD, and the notification signal. */
    sigemptyset(&sigs);
    sigaddset(&sigs, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&sigs, SIGHUP);
    sigaddset(&sigs, SIGCHLD);
    sigaddset(&sigs, NOTIFY_SIGNAL);
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigs, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot block the necessary signals: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Create the file. */
    page = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot create file: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (ftruncate(fd, page) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot resize file: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        unlink(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    close(fd);
    fd = -1;

    /* Ensure streams are flushed before forking. They should be, we're just paranoid here. */
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);

    /* Fork the mapper child process. */
    mapper = fork();
    if (mapper == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork mapper child process: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        unlink(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (!mapper) {
        fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
        if (fd == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "mapper_process(): %s: Cannot open file: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        status = mapper_process(fd, page);
        close(fd);
        return status;
    }

    /* For the writer child process. (mapper contains the PID of the mapper process.) */
    writer = fork();
    if (writer == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork writer child process: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        unlink(argv[1]);
        kill(mapper, SIGKILL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (!writer) {
        fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
        if (fd == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "writer_process(): %s: Cannot open file: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        status = writer_process(fd, page, mapper);
        close(fd);
        return status;
    }

    /* Wait for a signal. */
    if (duration.tv_sec || duration.tv_nsec)
        status = sigtimedwait(&sigs, &info, &duration);
    else
        status = sigwaitinfo(&sigs, &info);

    /* Whatever it was, we kill the child processes. */
    kill(mapper, SIGHUP);
    kill(writer, SIGHUP);
    do {
        p = waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
    } while (p != -1 || errno == EINTR);

    /* Cleanup. */
    unlink(argv[1]);

    printf("Done.\n");                 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that the child processes open the temporary file separately. To compile and run, use e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -O2 test-multi.c -o multi
./multi temp 10
```

The second parameter is the duration of the test, in seconds. (You can interrupt the testing safely using SIGINT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) or SIGHUP.)

On my machine, the test rate is roughly 120,000 tests per second; the `msync()` call is commented out here also, because I don't ever see any errors/desynchronization even without it. (Plus, `msync(ptr, len, MS_SYNC)` and `msync(ptr, len, MS_SYNC | MS_INVALIDATE)` are horribly slow; with either, I can get less than 1000 tests per second, with absolutely no difference in the results. That's a 100x slowdown.)

The `MAP_NORESERVE` flag to mmap tells it to use the file itself as backing storage when under memory pressure, rather than swap. If you compile the code on a system that does not recognize that flag, you can omit it. As long as the mapping is not evicted from RAM, the flag does not affect the operation at all.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I suspect (though not 100% sure yet) that the problem is from the other direction. It *seems* that the new data written to the file (via `write`) is not properly visible in the mapping. Even though I explicitly unmap & map the file after writing to it. Does it sounds reasonable, or perhaps I should look for the problem elsewhere?

Comment: @valdo: I cannot reproduce your results in Linux at all; the mapping and the file contents just stay in sync, even without using `msync()`. I wrote two tests: one single-process one, that accesses the mapping and file contents sequentially, and checks if the updates are correctly seen in the other; and one multi-process one, that uses a POSIX realtime signal to inform the other process that they should check the mapping/file contents, using an incrementing counter.

Comment: @valdo: I added the two test programs to this answer. Could you try running them? As I said, I use Linux proper, and I'm not even sure which systems it runs on.

Comment: First - a lot of thanks for the very detailed answer. I added a call to `msync` with `MS_SYNC | MS_INVALIDATE` after every mapped memory modification. And it seems to fix the problem. Of course I can't be 100% sure yet, but in typical scenarios where I could reproduce the problem easily - it doesn't reproduce anymore.

Comment: As for you test program: you test 2 cases: (1) modifying mapped memory, then reading from the file and comparing it. (2) vice-versa: write to file, then compare with mapped memory. Now, my case it somewhat different. I both write to the memory and to the file, then remap, and it sometimes *seems* not right. One of the possible explanations that I may think of is that file and memory writes actually occur on the same page, and since I didn't flush the memory write - somehow it got written wrong to the file.

Comment: @valdo: Very interesting. As you see, I did not write a test program where the file writer appends the file, and the mapper only reads and modifies existing data. Is that the *exact* pattern you have? I.e. file writer does not modify existing data, only appends to it? The mapper does not append to the file, only reads/modifies existing data? If so, I think I should add that as the third example/test program, since it does have slightly different semantics; it might be useful for others, too. (If your pattern differs, I'd like to replicate it.)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure this is so. The mapping is read-write (to be exact: created with `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED`).  What I actually do is manage some pretty complex data structure, which consists of some index, and then "records" containing the data. When the data should be added - the index is modified (via pointer to the mapped memory), and the data is always appended to the end of the file (via `write`)...

Comment: Of course the access to this structure is guarded by sync obj. What I see (before I added the `msync`) is that sometimes one thread modifies it, then another thread accesses it and discovers inconsistency. It also *seems* the problem is more likely to occur when there is no much data, but this may be due to many reasons: more extensive modifications, more chance the "reader" wants exactly this portion that was just appended. Or, as I tend to think now, this may be because the index and the newly-appended "record" actually fall on the same memory page, which could be a good explanation IMHO.

Comment: @valdo: Is the data appended by the same thread/process that also uses the mapping?  Or a different process? Or are there multiple processes that both map and write to the file?  I'm trying to construct a mental picture, so that I can write the third test case to match your pattern. (In particular, if there are multiple processes that append to the file, you probably need advisory file locking to serialize those too, unless they grab the sync object for the duration.)

Comment: I added the pseudo-code. `SaveGridCell()` and `DecodeGridCell()` are called from arbitrary thread (within the same process).

Comment: @valdo: Okay; I believe I now see. I have a final question: When you do a modification, why don't you simply extend the file (and the mapping whenever necessary)? I do not see any sensible reason for using write() at all here, you see.

Comment: So, you ask why I don't just resize the file mapping, so that the file underlying is extended appropriately? Well, good question, I actually could write all the data via file mapping to. One reason not to do this is probably to set the new file size more accurately, i.e. it should not be restricted to the page alignment.

Comment: @valdo: In POSIXy systems, you use `ftruncate()` to resize the file to any size you want. You only need to remap when the file size is greater than the mapped page-aligned range. (In other words, you can avoid remapping quite often, too.) Technically, when the last page in the mapping is sync'ed, the kernel just drops any bytes after the end of the file on the floor. (Accessing any mapped pages completely beyond the current end of the file will get you a SIGBUS, though.)

Comment: @valdo: ... which leads to an obvious solution. Just create a large enough mapping initially, say a gigabyte or so. Virtual memory is relatively cheap. As long as you don't try to access past the end of the file, you're safe. Whenever you grow the file, just `ftruncate()` it to the new size; no need to change the mapping.

Comment: ```/* msync(map, 2 * sizeof map[0], MAP_SYNC | MAP_INVALIDATE); */```
should be
```/* msync(map, 2 * sizeof map[0], MS_SYNC | MS_INVALIDATE); */```